# Yoast SEO makes repeated INSERT queries loading any page

Tags: plugin-wp-seo-yoast

By using Query Monitor plugin I found that Yoast SEO (Wordpress SEO) plugin makes repeated INSERT queries to the db when I load any page (dashboard and frontend) of my site.

```
INSERT INTO `wp_yoast_seo_meta` (`object_id`, 
`internal_link_count`)
VALUES ( '50845', '0' )
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE `object_id` = VALUES(`object_id`), `internal_link_count` = 
VALUES(`internal_link_count`)
```

I tried to disable the link suggestion feature in Yoast SEO settings, but the queries are still there.

Can someone give some hints how to solve that?

P.S. The problem is not only this. I also can't dismiss the Yoast SEO notices in the dashboard. When I dismiss the notice and I load any page, the notice is still there.

WP 4.9.8
Yoast SEO 9.1

Comment: It's best to ask this to Yoast. They have [a page explaining how to get support](https://kb.yoast.com/kb/support/).

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved. It seems that iThemes Security plugin was causing the problems.

After disabling and enabling iThemes Security, the problems with Yoast SEO seems to be solved.